# Stop user from getting data by changing id via URL

Tags: php, mysql

Showing user data on a page by query:

`$query = "SELECT * FROM COLLECTIONS WHERE uid = $_GET['user_id']"`;

But problem is that user can see other users data by changing that uid.
How to solve this problem.

Comment: You need to implement access control, checking that the collection belongs to the logged in user.

Comment: Other problem is.... **Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection and will be hacked** even if [you are escaping inputs!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5741264/2595450) Use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead.

Comment: Don't get the userid from a URL parameter. When the user logs in, set a session variable, and use that.

Comment: encrypt the user_id so the user will not change it.

Comment: Like this`$query = "SELECT * FROM COLLECTIONS WHERE uid = $_GET['$_SESSION['user_id']'];"` @barmar

Comment: @abrar that's too much

Comment: @RajeevMalik Basically just check if the user has the right to access the item from `collections` if so, show it

Comment: @RajeevMalik `$_SESSION['uid'] = $uid;`

Comment: How to do that @ mehdi

Comment: General approach is to get the item and see if the user has the right to see it (does the user own it), I can't tell for sure as I don't know what data are you storing in that table nor it's structure

Comment: what's the problem in using session variables, can u give me some example code of your approach @MehdiBounya

Comment: There is no problem with the approach @Barmar suggested

Comment: @RajeevMalik Is this a hobby website? I really hope you're making this just for fun, and nobody's storing their passwords or confidential data in this.

Comment: @MehdiBounya - I would say encrypting it is not enough, they would need to add a different random salt to each user's id, to prevent me from breaking any simple hashing they may attempt to do,

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix not sure if you are serious xD if you are, just checking for permissions is enough.

Comment: I am serious, you cant just hash the ID and think it's safe.  I could brake it because I know it's a number, all I would do is say it's 32 long, it's md5, then i hash my ID if its the same as that hash, well I can take another id and just hash it.  if it's not but has the same salt for everyone, then I can brute force that salt from my hash and user id, so it would have to be a random salt, which requires storing it, that was my point it's easier to do access control at that point.  I was replying specifically to this comment `encrypt the user_id so the user will not change it`

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix My comment was that hashing and encrypting is too much and unnecessary (as you said _it's easier to do access control at that point_), another simpler approach is to generate a unique key that is long enough to prevent brute forcing and store it along the primary key (int id), and use the unique key for public accessing.

Answer (score 0):

Take your website offline. ***NOW.*** Somebody is going to either wipe the data or steal the data or inject malware that's served to all of your customers

Breathe. You've bought yourself some time, assuming it hasn't already been breached.

### A small subset of the security measures you NEED to take

These mitigate, in order of "has biggest immediate benefits" to "is probably most important", one problem each. (Apart from number 3, which mitigates anywhere from 4 to 32241 problems of equal or greater magnitude to number 1.)

1. Look through every instance of every database request, and make sure that you are never using double quotes or the `.` operator when defining your query string. Rebuild all of your database handling code to use some sort of [parametrised SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4712037/5223757) system.
2. Use an authentication library, or at the *very least* a crypto library.
3. Ask about your setup on [Security Stack Exchange](https://security.stackexchange.com) using an account that is in no way traceable to your website. Not even to your company, if your website is associated with your company.

### Why?

Yes, I know, that website is probably important and needs to stay up so people can use it. But try this:

```
www.badwebsite.com/your/page/here?uid=1 OR 1
```

*All* of the data is visible! You are accepting code from the user and running it in your database. Now what if I decided to delete all of your database tables?

That's just covering the first point I made. Please trust that there are bigger problems for your users if you haven't done step 2, the least of which is hundreds of their accounts on other websites (e.g. Gmail, Example Bank) becoming known to cyber criminals.

Take a look at this comic strip:

[image: The server crashes if the user's password is a resolvable URL.]

> There's also a unicode-handling bug in the URL request library, and we're storing the passwords unsalted ... so if we salt them with emoji, we can close three issues at once!

This is made to be more funny, but the problem described in this comic strip is probably *less bad* than the problem you are facing. Please, for the sake of whoever has entrusted you with their data, turn it off for a few days whilst you try to make it something resembling secure.

You might want to bring in a technical consultant; if your developers are not experienced in creating intrusion-proof software then they're probably not up to the task of making insecure software secure (which is orders of magnitude harder, especially if you're new to that sort of thing).

Comment: That injection `"1;CREATE TABLE you_have_lost (number int);"`won't work op PHP's MySQL clients because they dont  support separated SQL statements separated with semicon (`;`)... Your just getting a error instead without executing the queries and without created table.... unless offcource you are using mysqli_multi_qeury() then your SQL injection would work..

Comment: @RaymondNijland Thanks. Can you think of a simple, easy to understand demonstration of an injection that _would_ work in this case? Some way of reading all of the data? (I don't think SQL's as bad as JavaScript in that regard.)

Comment: @RaymondNijland That's the classic case; I don't know why I didn't think of it. Thanks!

Comment: The php page could just show one record in that case add `LIMIT 1`,  `LIMIT 1, 1`, `LIMIT 2, 1` end so on to the SQL injection see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b3f901/9

Comment: @RaymondNijland Why don't you make the edit, so you're credited in the edit history?

Comment: I would do `1 OR 1; -- ` comment the rest of the SQL, then no `LIMIT`  Here is you limit fiddle I just hacked it http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b3f901/11